# woocommerce - calc shipping on checkout page after country entry

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, woocommerce

I'm using Woocommerce for Wordpress to build a webshop.

I've altered the checkout page a bit. I want the shipping to be calculated after the customer has entered his/her country. Any ideas?

Thanks!